# Adding bundle items to cart creates recursive dependency error

Tags: magento-1.9, bundle-product

Item at http://wenderella.com/castaging/index.php/fruit-basket.html

It is a bundle product, a fruit basket, with dynamic pricing. Each fruit is a simple product with no stock management.

Option 1 (Required): Add a fruit - watermelon, pineapple or honeydew - Dropdown input, you can select qty of fruits you want

Option 2 (Not Required): Add another fruit - watermelon, pineapple or honeydew - Dropdown input, you can select qty of fruits you want

When I just add Option 1 or Option 2 to cart, there's no problem, it goes through.

But if I select something in both options (e.g. I choose a watermelon in option 1, then a pineapple in option 2), the following error occurs:

> Fatal error: Nesting level too deep - recursive dependency? in /home/blacklea/public_html/wenderella.com/castaging/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item/Abstract.php on line 134

I followed all steps to create a bundle product exactly (or so I think). What am I doing wrongly??

I have tried disabling all extensions and the error remains.

Version: CE 1.9.3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Modify `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item/Abstract.php` as stated below – only difference is `, true` being added to `in_array()` – and see if the exception disappears:

```
public function setParentItem($parentItem)
{
    if ($parentItem) {
        $this->_parentItem = $parentItem;
        // Prevent duplication of children in those are already set
        if (!in_array($this, $parentItem->getChildren(), true)) {
            $parentItem->addChild($this);
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

NB: Bear in mind that you're overriding a core file so for a more permanent solution you should either override the (child) class via a custom module or at least copy the vanilla file to `app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item/Abstract.php` and modify that one.

Comment: Hello, thanks for trying to help! I have done the above and updated the results in my question. Strangely, if it's of any significance, when I first added the code to Abstract.php,  I managed to add 2 bundle items to the cart (error free). But that just happened once and the error happened again afterwards.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help, you can remove the stack trace from your question as well as the code snippet from your method. Please see updated answer.

Comment: That worked! Fantastic! Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: Glad to help :) Please mark the answer as such and consider upvoting if it was of any use to you.

Comment: BTW: which php version and os platform are you using? I'm asking since in my case it worked without the fix.

Comment: PHP version is 4.0.10.14, I'm using Mac Sierra

Comment: Problem seems to occur in PHP 7.3

Comment: @ahe_borriglione This is a fix for really old and outdated php versions only (that probably never met Magento’s system requirements), you won’t need it for versions ~5+.

Comment: @pong No, I got this error in PHP 7.3.9 and it seems to be connected to the setting of php.ini's `pcre.recursion_limit`

Comment: @ahe_borriglione that should’ve been a comment on the question at most then, not on this answer. are you sure 7.3 is supported by your magento version?

Comment: @ahe_borriglione but it’s not the same line being logged as the cause, is it? i don’t see any relationship between pcre and the in_array-check.

Comment: Here's the information on why the error happens: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19097159/3481240

Comment: Btw, if you're using OpenMage LTS, `,true` is already there - as we can see in [their code](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/blob/1.9.4.x/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item/Abstract.php#L271)